# Lua reference table inside metatable

Tags: oop, lua, metatable

I have a pretty mind-bending setup right now. I have a regular function that returns a table with functions in it under keys "string" and "number":

```
function defGeneric()
    local function funcNumber(a)
        return 2*a^2
    end
    local function funcString(a)
        return a.." - test"
    end
    local returnTable={}
    returnTable["number"]=funcNumber
    returnTable["string"]=funcString
    return returnTable
end
```

And that works fine. But what I want to do now is make the table that this function returns callable. To illustrate, let's say we have `v=defGeneric()`. Specifically:

1. If `v` is called with a string `str`, return the result of `v["string"](str)`
2. If `v` is called with a number `n`, return the result of `v["number"](n)`

This is obviously a job for metatables, so I can (in my function) add the code to set a metatable:

```
local metaTable = {
        __call = function (...) -- "call" event handler
            return  
        end
    }
setmetatable(returnTable,metaTable)
```

But I don't know what I would put after that return statement. I don't think I can reference returnTable, because this table will be called like so:

```
v=defGeneric()
v("test")
```

And I need to reference `v`'s "string" function (there certainly could be multiple defGeneric() tables in one program).

I think the answer here might be some `self` trick but I can't wrap my head around how. How do I reference a metatable's table from the metatable?

Comment: `__call = function(t,x) return t[type(x)](x) end`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Just figured that out! Thank you! Post that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument passed to the `__call` function is the table it is being called on, the table returned from the function in this case.  You can use `type(a)` to get the type of the argument as a string, so you could do something like this:

```
function defGeneric()
  local result = {
    ['number'] = function(a) return 2*a^2 end,
    ['string'] = function(a) return a.." - test" end
  }
  setmetatable(result, {
    __call = function(t,a)
      local f = t[type(a)]
      if f == nil then return "No handler for type "..type(a) end
    -- alternate:
    -- if f == nil and t['string'] ~= nil then return t['string'](tostring(a)) end

      return f(a)
    end
  })
  return result
end

local def = defGeneric()
print("string: "..tostring(def('sample string')))
print("number: "..tostring(def(5)))
print("table: "..tostring(def({})))
print("boolean: "..tostring(def(1 > 5)))
```

*output*

```
string: sample string - test
number: 50.0
table: No handler for type table
boolean: No handler for type boolean
```

*alternate output*

```
string: sample string - test
number: 50.0
table: table: 0x18537e0 - test
boolean: false - test
```